# How to remember channels where bot is enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot using discord.js and node.js.

Essentially, the bot needs to a message every predefined amount of time.

To not send a message to every channel of every server the bot is in, I made an enable-disable system:

when you type !enable, the bot saves in an array the channel and when it needs to send a message, for each channel in the array, it sends a message to that channel.

The problem is that when I update/restart the bot, that array is gone, so I have to re-type !enable in every channel I need.

This is the code that handles the !enable and !disable

```
enabled_channels = [];

client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith("!")) {
        if(message.content === "!enable") {
            if(!enabled_channels.includes(message.channel)) {
                enabled_channels.push(message.channel);
                message.channel.send("Bot enabled in this channel");
            } else {
                message.channel.send("Bot already enabled in this channel");
            }
        } else if(message.content === "!disable") {
            if(enabled_channels.includes(message.channel)) {
                enabled_channels.splice(enabled_channels.indexOf(message.channel), 1)
            }
            message.channel.send("Bot disabled in this channel");
        }
    }
});
```

And this is the code that sends the message to all the channels

```
function sendToAll(message) {
    for(let c of enabled_channels) {
        c.send(message);
    }
}

setInterval(() => {
    var message = functionThatGenerateTheMessageContent();  //really simplified here
    sendToAll(message);
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);  //5 minutes
```

Is there a way to save the `enabled_channels` array? I tried with `node-localstorage` but I found that saving an object, just saves `[Object object]` and saving the stringified object saves only the attributes and not the type so I cannot call functions associated with that object.

Comment: Its not really possible to save object with all its methods. Your best option would be to save an array of channel IDs and then use `client.channels.fetch(id)` to fetch each channel and send a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use a SQLite database, and save a user input channel in the db, then loop through and send a message to them all.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3
This is a faster, easier sqlite package - the docs will help you on anything you need